# If $A \subseteq R$ and $f \colon A \to R$ has a limit at $c \in R$, then $f$ is bounded on some neighborhood of $c$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let's look at the proof given in my textbook.

If $L := \lim_{x \to c}{f(x)}$, then for $\varepsilon = 1$, there exists some positive $\delta$ that if $0<|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<1$.

So if $c \notin A$, we take $M = |L|+1$, while if $c \in A$ we take $M:= \sup\{|f(c)|,|L|+1\}$.

It follows that if $x \in A \cap V_\delta(c)$, then $|f(x)| \le M$. This shows that $f$ is bounded on the neighbourhood $V_\delta(c)$ of $c$.

My question is when we take the limit at $c$ then we don't care if the function is defined at $c$. So if the function is not defined at $c$ and the limit exists at $c$ then how can we define $M:= \sup\{|f(c)|,|L|+1\}$?

So is the theorem wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Hey Chanakya, welcome to math.stackexchange! I've edited your question to use MathJax. This is used throughout math.se, and a good tutorial can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1108193).

Comment: If $c \notin A$ then $M=|L|+1$.

Comment: $f:X\to Y$ means $f$ is defined at every point of $X.$

Comment: Alternatively, if the result fails, then $f$ is unbounded on every neighborhood of $c.$ Then for each integer $n$ there exists a neighborhood $U_n$ on which at least one value of $f$ exceeds $n,$ so let $x_n \in U_n$ be a point such that $f(x_n) > n.$ By choosing the $U_n$'s to be open intervals whose lengths approach zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$ (details left to you), we have $x_n \rightarrow c$ and $f(x_n) \rightarrow \infty.$

Answer (score 1):

You are right that if $f$ is not defined at $c$, then $M:= \sup\{|f(c)|,|L|+1\}$ is not defined. But the proof takes care of this case. It says that if $f(c)$ is not defined, then take $M = |L| + 1$.

In the case that $f(c)$ is not defined, it holds that for all $x$ in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$, $|f(x)| \le M$ whenever $f(x)$ is defined.